# Run HTML page in Chrome

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code running on Windows 10, I am trying to run a plain HTML page in Chrome using a startup script in my workspace definition. When I run the site, chrome opens to the correct URL but I get the error below stating the connection was refused. The chrome browser that opens is not the same chrome browser I use when I just browse the internet on my own. My preferences are not set and there are not any user profiles. Has anyone else experienced this behavior?

```
    {
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {},
    "launch": {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "mypage",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/index.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

[image: ErrorMessage]

Comment: Which OS is it running on?

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: is there something hosting that port on your local machine?  If you browse to http://localhost:8080/index.html in Chrome stand alone do you get a response?

Comment: @ScottMildenberger, valid point, and no I am not. But if I remove the http://localhost:8080 from the url it still tries to go there. Since I am only running static files I really don't need a webserver. Is there a way to configure it to point to just the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run the files by changing the URL to point to the file directly. It seems even if you leave out the protocol, VS Code defaults it to HTTP. Even though my description had the HTTP URL defined, I also tried removing it. @ScottMildenburger comment got me to reevaluate that logic and find the answer. Thank you Scott!

```
"launch": {
        "configurations": [
            {
                "type": "chrome",
                "request": "launch",
                "name": "Launch Chrome against Samples Index",
                "url": "file:///${workspaceFolder}/index.html"         
            }
        ]
```